# Uses Cases for the Calendar Widget

Tags: widgets

So I've looked at several themes and visited several theme dev sites and i'm confused about the "purpose" of the WordPress Calendar Widget.

So it states it is...

> A calendar of your site’s Posts

But really? Is that all it is used for? Surely there are more creative uses for this widget. Is anyone using it in any creative way?

**Edit**

The Question is - how you would modify the calendar widget to extend its functionality for custom purposes.

Comment: Ehm, but it doesn't _do_ anything else?..

Comment: The request for examples of creative uses at the end of your question makes your question open ended. I would advise you remove it and instead ask how you would modify the calendar widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it sits, the calendar widget pretty much does just what you've said—allows people to troll the archives.

Of course, it can be modified for different uses. One site I worked on used the [Future](http://wordpress.org/plugins/future/) plugin to convert the WordPress calendar widget into a calendar of events by creating a post for each event whose "date published" field was set to the date the event had happened in the past or would happen in the future.

Comment: That future plugin is indeed an interesting use case. Opens the mind to the possibilities. Thanks again.

Comment: @sleeper: Glad I could help. =)